# MYSQL - regex for SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

How can I modify the SQL query below with regex to get this result (the folder structure is not static) ?

SQL Query:

```
SELECT name, identifier 
FROM mydb 
WHERE uid = 123 and type='image'
```

RESULT

```
COLUMN: name
ROW:my_pic.jpg
COLUMN: identifier
ROW:/global/images/example/my_pic.jpg
```

What i need is this result remove everything after last slash for column identifier

```
COLUMN: name
ROW:my_pic.jpg
COLUMN: identifier
ROW:/global/images/example/
```

Comment: Moved the question up top to lead off with it

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select left(col, length(col) - length(substring_index(col, '/', -1)))
```

It finds the length of everything after the last `'/'` and then removes those characters.

Comment: can you show me the detailed syntax for my example?

Comment: I suspect you just want to replace `col` with `identifier`, but I do not fully understand the format you are using to show the results in your question, so that is just a guess.